# delete data from a table variable from a function

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, dynamic-sql

i have a Stored procedure that insert at it's beginning data into a **table variable**,
after that i want to **delete records** selected, but i cant delete them directly, so my solution is to make a **function** that delete my data from the **table variable** and call it from the SP, 
but the problem is how to make a **dynamic delete query** and how to access the table variable from the SP?

Comment: give an example on how you want to delete your records and i will write you the dynamic sql.

Comment: i am with theweeknd, you need to post some more details such as the proc or the expected input and output.  Sounds like the solution would be easy enough, but its just not clear what your after.

Comment: Why can't you delete the data directly, if you can insert it?  It's not a matter of dynamic sql, but rather table variable persistency. There are global temp tables.  But I would suggest avoiding them unless no other solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a SP for this then look at this solution.

At the beginig I'm creating a table data type for storing selected ids.

```
create type SelectedTable as table 
( 
    SelectedId int 
);
go
```

You can edit this type with fields matching your mentioned table variable.

Then I'm creating a stored procedure that get parameter as table and delete some data from some table - this is a solution for passing a table into SP.

```
create procedure dbo.deleteSelectedRecords  
    @selectedIdTable SelectedTable readonly 
    as   
    set nocount on
        delete from dbo.some_table_with_data_to_delete
        where id_of_selected_record in (select SelectedId from @selectedIdTable)
go
```

In this moment of the example I will prepare the table with sample of selected ids.

```
declare @TempTable as SelectedTable;
insert into @TempTable (SelectedId) values (1), (2), (5), (12);
```

And at the end we can call the SP and delete selected elements with it.

```
exec dbo.deleteSelectedRecords @TempTable;
```

But I think that you don't need another SP or function or even dynamic SQL to do that. You can use query like this below simply inside your SP where you have access to your table variable

```
delete from dbo.some_table_with_data_to_delete
where id_of_selected_record in (select SelectedId from @TableVariable)
```